# Set my current user as root user

Tags: mac, sudo

I just got my freshly repaired macbook back. On the old version of it, I had run a command to stop getting `access denied` when trying to install from the terminal without using `sudo`. I don't remember what was that command, so I added my current user in the `sudoers` through visudo. Despite this, when I try to `cat /etc/sudoers` without sudo, I still get `access denied`.

Comment: Does `sudo cat /etc/sudoers` work?

Comment: MacOS has lots of additional security features, so that even if you add your user to the sudo list, or make yourself root, it's still not the pointless gaping security hole it could be.

Comment: @benwiggy Editing sudoers will never remove the need of running/using sudo to get to root in the first place.

Comment: @nohillside yes it works fine

Comment: You could do things like `alias scat='sudo cat'` and then just run `scat /etc/sudoers` if needed. But you can't avoid the use of `sudo`..

Comment: If you're asking why `sudo` doesn't work after you've added your username to `sudoers`, I wonder if it might be a good idea to share **what exactly** you entered?